# Keep screen awake Ionic (Insomnia)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

Hie, i make an app and i need that the screen keep awake without use an external app.
I try to install insomnia but i think this method doesn't work and display "error".

```
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia/ngx';

public insomnia: Insomnia,

this.insomnia.keepAwake()
    .then(
      () => console.log('success'),
      () => console.log('error')
    );
```

I put this code in ng on init to avoid the screen lock.
I use Ionic 5.
Do you know a method to help me or an other plugin ?
Thank you for you help.
(don't pay attention to spelling mistakes i'm french sorry)

Comment: How do you want to implement this function.. on a specific page or it will be for complete app .. like when you use this application it will never go in sleep .. or only if you are on detail page or any other specific page it will not go into sleep.. please let us know so that we can share our opinion

Comment: I want implement this function in complete app.component.ts.

Comment: yeah thats what i was asking to do this in app.component.ts file

Comment: I try a specific page but not working i always have 'error' in console.

Comment: Since you are already doing this in app component file . i am not sure either its like we will have to debug whole app

Comment: what error do you have can you please paste it to

Comment: This function work for you ? Or juste don't working for me ?

Comment: it should work for all . yeah it worked for me i tried more then a year ago . not today

Comment: by the way which OS you are trying ios or android

Comment: I try in android device.  and i have this error but i think it's don's this . ```Native: tried calling Insomnia.keepAwake, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator```

Comment: Do one thing uninstall the plugin and install it again .. sometime it may cause an issue

Comment: i did this ```ionic cordova platform add browser

ionic cordova run browser``` to start a cordova browser so i have 'error' in the console

Comment: it should work .. they have clearly mentioned that it wil work for browser .. well i try this in android and ios ..let me try with browser if this cause an issue at my end or not

Comment: I uninstall and install @ionic-native/insomnia. but it's same 'error' not 'success'

Comment: no not this module uninstall the plugin .. `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-insomnia`

Comment: I remove codrdova-plugin-insomnia and reinstall but it's same('error') ...

Comment: while i run `ionic cordova run browser` it says `Insomnia is not supported on the browser`

Comment: but when i run this in android device it works for me perfectly

Comment: After, update the plugin and install the app in real device. It worked !